# Python constants

Tags: python, django, constants

I am in the middle of a development in Django and we got some doubts about if we should use or not constants in the project. Exactly the situation is to use constants everywhere or not (we know constants in Django are not really read-only).

There are 2 scenarios and I would like to get your opinion about which one is better for you and why:

## Scenario 1 (using constants)

### constants.py

```
class CONST():
    def NAME(): return "name"
    def SURNAME(): return "surname"
    def ZIPCODE(): return "zipcode"
    def CITY(): return "city"
    def CREATED(): return "created"
```

### admin.py

```
from constants import CONST
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (CONST.NAME(),CONST.SURNAME(),CONS.ZIPCODE())
    list_filter = [CONST.ZIPCODE(),CONST.CITY()]
    search_fields = [CONST.NAME(), CONST.SURNAME()]
    date_hierarchy = CONST.CREATED()
```

### models.py

```
from constants import CONST
class Register(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(CONST.NAME(), max_length=25)
    surname = models.CharField(CONST.SURNAME(), max_length=25)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(CONST.ZIPCODE())
    city = models.CharField(CONST.CITY(),max_length=20)
```

*... and any view etc where you use text will be using contants ...*

## Scenario 2 (without constants)

### admin.py

```
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name","surname","zipcode")
    list_filter = ["zipcode","city"]
    search_fields = ["name","surname"]
```

### models.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=25)
    surname = models.CharField("surname", max_length=25)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField("zipcode")
    city = models.CharField("city",max_length=20)
```

I like the most the second scenario (I have been programming python from 2004), for me it looks more efficient, clear and easy to understand. The first scenario (proposed from Java/PHP programmers that now writes Python code) has the advantage that it helps the developer to detect that it made a mistake writing the "constant" so it is easier to detect errors and also it makes easier and quicker "massive changes" on this kind of texts without refactorizing the source code.

I would like to know which source code you would write or use and why.

Thank you,

Comment: Scenario 1 is horrible in my opinion.

Comment: You should not be using 'constants' there at all, as the *database schema* depends on those as well. Change your constants and your schema requires a migration.. The first scenario is *very far* from being Pythonic; even simple attributes would do better than methods. Your Java/PHP programmers introduced complexities for reasons that smack of YAGNI; *You aint gonna need it*.

Comment: I would be worried about anything that allows it to be easier to implement _"massive changes"_ **on the schema.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1 doesn't make sense. You're using the constants to specify the [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) of the fields, and you're using them in the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option. The `list_display` option takes a list of fieldnames and NOT the `verbose_name` of the fields.

So you don't need constants at all for this. The field names are your "constants".

And IF you would need some "constants" in some case, you shouldn't use methods, just use properties, and just use normal class/attribute name conventions (so no uppercases):

```
class SomeConstants():
    name = "name"
    surname = "surname"
    zipcode = "zipcode"
    city = "city"
    created = "created"
```

The Java/PHP guys might say something like *"Yeah but what if one of the constants needs to be generated? Then you need a method!"*. Well, sure, so you make it a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class SomeConstants():

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.surname)
```

Because of the `@property` line above the method, it will execute and return the result of this method if you call `SomeConstants().full_name`.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 1 is awful.  Unfortunately I know all too well the problems of working with Java/PHP developers who are learning python.

Perhaps you can compromise with those guys by proposing the use of [python enums](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) to address their concern.  These are built-in in python 3.4+, and have been [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) as far back as 2.4.

```
from enum import Enum

class Constant(Enum):
    name = "name"
    surname = "surname"
    zipcode = "zipcode"
    city = "city"
    created = "created"
```

Now you can change the "values", say for example changing zipcode to be "potato" in the enum definition, whilst still using the name `Constant.zipcode.value` everywhere else in source code.

Comment: Their purpose is to keep it "constant" but there are no contants in Python, I did a Contant.name=3 and it worked and changed the value to 3. So I still don't see the point of having this kind of constants out from the model/admin/from/etc... declaration.

Comment: Yes.  So what?  Scenario 1 doesn't prevent that either.

Comment: You can approximate read-only by using python properties, if that's what you think you need ..

Comment: Alternatively you can put them as attributes on a plain old class, and then override `__setattr__` to raise exception.  But it's not really adding value to your code.

Comment: @wim What's the use of making a string constants class inherit `Enum`?

Comment: You have .name and .value on the enum instances, and they have some identity i.e. they won't compare equal with other random strings which are containing the same value (and that is a Good Thing™). You also get some other nice features such as aliases, read the PEP about enums for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use of constants is sometimes good, but *not here*.

One, the first argument of a field is its *verbose name*, if it's missing then the name of the field is used by default. So using the same constant for its verbose name as for the field name is exactly the scenario in which the verbose name is completely unnecessary.

Just do

```
name = CharField(max_length=25)
```

or

```
name = CharField("A beautiful description for a name field", max_length=25)
```

but putting "name" there is completely redundant and thus wrong. Don't repeat yourself.

Second, your constant is actually used for two different things that you don't want to change at the same time: you use the same constant for the attribute name in admin.py, but for verbose name in models.py. They aren't going to stay the same thing.

Third, using constants is only really helpful if the value *might change one day*, or if *it's not immediately obvious what it may mean*, for e.g. PI=3.14.

But `NAME = "name"` does not make anything more obvious, and if it ever changes to `NAME = "description"` it immediately becomes actively misleading. You'd probably want to change the name of the constant in that case as well, won't you? Why did you ever use a constant then?

And it means that changing something in `const.py` changes the database structure that Django expects. Some day a developer is going to trip over that; keep field names in `models.py`.

Finally, at every place where you *use* the models, you need the actual field anyway. A `Register` instance is simply a class instance, after all, and you'll probably want to use fields like `register.name` anywhere. You don't put the names of attributes of other classes in constants, do you?

Just use the string.

Comment: The problem is not about the verbose name, I wrote the examples like that to make it look simpler. The real question is about constants yes/no and where.

Comment: One typical use is for the `choices` argument of a field, they're usually defined as class attributes of the model they belong to, in CAPS so others know that they're constants. Otherwise, the Django philosophy leans heavily on "don't repeat yourself" so there's not much use for constants -- everything should have a single point of definition already. Typical configuration constants can go into Django's `settings.py` (or `conf.py`, see the `django-appconf` app)

Answer (score 1):

What about something more straight-forward like:

constants.py

```
NAME = "name"
SURNAME = "surname"
```

admin.py

```
import constants
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (constants.NAME, constants.SURNAME,constants.ZIPCODE)
```

This provides a unique place for the values in contrast to repeating them as in Scenario 2 and thus I would prefer it. It seems more clear than Scenario 1 to me. The "encapsulation" is performed by the module name, i.e. by using `constants.xxx`, so don't `from constants import *`.

The values here are obviously not constant, but neither are they in Scenario 1.

Comment: This is the way Django does it.  And, in my opinion, it was an ugly mistake - unfortunately now too ingrained in the framework to change.

Comment: I still believe using constants this way it would mean to put outside the context important details that belongs to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is in agreement that its a bad idea, but it could be that your Java friends are trying to implement the equivalent of a [Java resource bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_resource_bundle), perhaps because they fondly remember how easy it is to work with [`.properties` files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

This results in the use of keys in place of actual names and then later on the system will retrieve the correct resource from the bundle. This technique is used for translations and localization of applications.

A typical resource key looks like `key.trx.hist.term.transfer.completed.success` and at runtime the equivalent resource is rendered by the application.

If this is the case, in Python the approach is a bit different:

1. You start with a *base language*. This is what you write your code in.
2. All strings that need to be localized or translated are *marked for translation*, with the [`gettext` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html). For convenience this library provides a shortcut method `_()` which is used to mark strings for translation.
3. These strings are then extracted to a *message file*; which is forwarded to translators. The message file contains the file names where the string is used. Its a plain text file, much like the .properties file.
4. This message file is then compiled into an optimized format.
5. Based on the language/locale of the client, the correct translated strings are displayed.

You can read more on how this is implemented in django at the [translation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/).

Comment: We know gettext and use _(), I believe they try to centralize the strings in one place...not sure!

Comment: That's the only equivalent in Java that I am aware of that would centralize strings; if its not that - then I suspect its a case of [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) as Martijn pointed out.